# Correspondence for $U_p$ operator

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, modular-forms, arithmetic-geometry, hecke-algebras

I've seen in many places that one can define the usual Hecke operator $T_p$ via correspondences by $(\pi_1)_*(\pi_2^*(\bullet))$ in the diagram
$$Y \xleftarrow{\pi_1} Y_0(p) \xrightarrow{\pi_2} Y$$
where $Y$ has trivial level structure at $p$, $Y_0(p)$ is the modular curve given by adding $\Gamma_0(p)$ level to $Y$, $\pi_1$ is the map which forgets the $p$-subgroup on the level of moduli, and $\pi_2$ is the map quotienting by the $p$-subgroup on the level of moduli.

I'd like to see a reference for the analogous correspondence for $U_p$, when $Y$ has nontrivial level structure at $p$ already, especially in the case where $Y$ has full $p$-level structure. I have a guess as to what it is, but a reference would be very helpful, especially if it also described the compatibility between $U_p$ and $T_p$ geometrically. Can anyone give such a reference?

Comment: possibly section 7.3 of [Modular forms and modular curves by Diamond and Im](https://people.math.wisc.edu/~nboston/Diamond-Im-Modular_forms_and_modular_curves.pdf) helps you